# How to parse angular elements metadata from source code

Tags: angular, parsing, metadata, element

Lately I have been trying to auto generate documentation for my angular elements based on their inputs/outputs and comments, however I didn't manage to find anything. What I look for is something similar to compodocs but that would output a data structure of my angular components with the component description (comments) as well as their inputs/outputs consolidated with  their associated types/comments so that I can associate them to the angular elements and generate the proper documentation.
For example let's say I have the following component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

/*
  Component displaying "Hello {{nameInput}}" where nameInput is an input
*/
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `
        Hello {{nameInput}}
      `
})
export class HelloComponent {
  /*
    name that should be displayed after 'Hello '
  */
  @Input()
  public nameInput: string;

  constructor(){}
}
```

I would like a json output that looks like:

```
[
  {
    "HelloComponent":
      {
        "description": "Component displaying \"Hello {{name}}\" where name is an input",
        "inputs": [
          {
            "name": "nameInput",
            "type": "string",
            "description": "name that should be displayed after 'Hello '"
          }
        ]
      }
  }
]
```

Is there a library that already does something similar?

**EDIT**: I had a closer look at Compodoc and it actually enables to generate the documentation in json which is exactly what I am looking for:
compodoc src/tsconfig.json -e json

Comment: https://compodoc.app/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a closer look at Compodoc and it actually enables to generate the documentation in json which is exactly what I am looking for: compodoc src/tsconfig.json -e json